# How to search including drop down option?

Tags: javascript, html

How do I create a search including a dropdown menu option. The `place.url.startsWith(shopOne, shopTwo)` doesn't display all the results (using both variables in the function) It seems like its ignoring the second variable `shopTwo` . I'm planning on having a lot more "shopX" added so like shopThree, shopFour and so on but to start and test with, the current code does not work and only uses the first variable. Is there a way to fix this?

HTML

```
 <select class="custom-select1" >
        <option value="" selected>All Counties</option>
        <option value="https://centra.,https://www.tesco.">Carlow</option>
        <option value="https://www.lidl.,https://centra.">Cavan</option>
    </select>
```

JAVASCRIPT

```
function findMatchesForCountiesAndShops(wordToMatch, shopOne, shopTwo, shops, name) {
        const regEx = new RegExp(wordToMatch, 'gi');
        return name.filter(place => {
            return regEx.test(place.name) && place.url.startsWith(shopOne, shopTwo)  && place.url.startsWith(shops);
        });
    }


function displayMatches() {
const searchText = document.querySelector('.search').value;

const shops = document.querySelector('.custom-select').value;
// const counties = document.querySelector('.custom-select1').value;
// const shops = document.querySelector('.custom-select1').value;
  var valueOne= $('.custom-select1').val().split(',')[0];
  var valueTwo =$('.custom-select1').val().split(',')[1]; 
  var shopOne = valueOne;
  var shopTwo = valueTwo;
  // const shopOne = "https://centra";
  // const shopTwo = "https://www.tesco.";


// C https://www.tesco. https://centra. https://www.tesco.

const matchArray = findMatchesForCountiesAndShops(searchText, shopOne, shopTwo, shops, name);
```

Comment: The [`String.prototype.startsWith()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/startsWith) method takes two parameters. The first is the string that you are searching for, and the second parameter is the position to begin searching from.

Comment: That will not work as I want to include 2 (and more in the future) to startWith.